# How to reference an Azure SDK tool in the build file?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-target

I need to execute the following Windows Azure SDK tool using the `Exec` task:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.3\bin\cspack.exe
```

What is the best way to reference this path in my `.build` file?

A direct reference, like below, it likely not to work on all hosts (build servers and development machines):

```
<Target Name="CreatePackage" DependsOnTargets="Build" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.2\bin\cspack.exe /parameters"></Exec>
</Target>
```

(Note: I do not want to use the CSPack task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rule of thumb is to either use `ToolLocationHelper` class, or a registry property `$(registry:Hive\Foo)`, or fire up something like Rapid Environment Editor and choose a variable that would give me the shortest, most fault-tolerant path. In this case you don't have much of a choice, the best you can do is to have an item `Include="$(ProgramW6432)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\**\bin\cspack.exe"` that would  protect against different architectures, non-default paths and versions, or if it's part of a bigger script run `setenv.cmd` first and use `$(ServiceHostingSDKInstallPath)`. You can also try running `msbuild foo.build /v:diag > foo.txt` and look through the evaluated properties dump, but the various SDK paths would depend on if you're running x86 or x64 MSBuild and would be developer specific.